# Stationarity test result interpratation Using NumXL

Tags: excel, time-series

I am currently using NumXL for my thesis. Is there a way to interpret the results of stationarity test. It would be great if there was a table describing if the time series are white noise, random walk etc according to every possible test result.

The results for the test are: 
Stationary test     Stationary?
ADF                   TRUE/FALSE
No Const              TRUE/FALSE
Const-Only            TRUE/FALSE
Const + Trend         TRUE/FALSE
Const+Trend+Trend^2   TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test for white-noise or stationarity? Those are two different concepts:
(1) For lack of serial correlation in the data set, use the white-noise test
(2) For stable conditional mean over time, use the stationary test.

In the output table of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) Test, we are examining the stationarity assumption under different scenarios:
- No Constant: The time series has zero mean
- Const-Only: the data series has a non-zero mean.
- Const + Trend: The time series has a deterministic trend
- Const+Trend+Trend^2: the time series has quadratic trend curve over time.

The ADF tests only for the presence of unit-root (aka random walk),  which translate into a stable conditional mean for the time series.

If your data is showing TRUE for "Constant-only" (2) scenario, then you may assume that your data is stationary, but has a non-zero mean. In this case, stop here, and ignore the deterministic linear and quadratic trend scenarios.

To establish whether the time series is pure white-noise, then we need to do a portmanteau test such as ljung-box in the white-noise test. This will test the lack of significant autocorrelation for any number of lags.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. So i cannot assume the behaviour of the time series from ADF test?

The ADF tests only for the presence of unit-root (aka random walk), which translate into a stable conditional mean for the time series.
How will i u see the random walk?

Im sorry for the questions, but i am new and i am trying to understand

Comment: random walk means the presence of a unit-root.  So, if what are you looking for is a proof of random walk, then stationary test is what you want.